# Using indexOf to search an array of objects for a certain property

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array set like `tempArray[i] = {Name: 'foo', Data: 'bar'}`
How would you use `indexOf` to search through `tempArray` looking to see if the name element was present?
I.e

```
if(tempArray.indexOf('foo') > -1)
{
 //do stuff
}
```

Ive tried this way but it never seems to be true because I think 'foo' is not accessible due to it being reference by the `.Name`

Comment: `tempArray[i].Name.indexOf('foo')` is the right way.. incase if a big array then iterate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just check for the property?

tempArray[i] = {Name: 'foo', Data: 'bar'}

```
if(tempArray[i].name)
{
 //do stuff
}
```

Comment: If `name` is falsy (evaluates to `false` like `0`, `false`, `null`) then it would also fail, despite existing.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to search through the array for an object with `Name` property:

```
//this assumes tempArray has objects only!
for(var i = 0, len = tempArray.length; i< len; i++){
  if(tempArray[i].hasOwnProperty('Name')) {

    //do stuff
  }
}
```

Comment: after that check you need to a `indexOf` operation like `if(tempArray[i].Name.indexOf('foo') > -1) {}`

Comment: @Praveen `Object.prototype.indexOf === undefined    //true`. In other words, `tempArray[i]` is an object and not an array!

Comment: I thought OP is looking for the `array` elements with `Name` as `foo`

Comment: That doesn't really make sense. Array is a list and not a dictionary/key-reference

Answer (score 0):

That is an `object`, and you can do this to check that the `Name` property is present:

```
for (var i = 0; i < tempArray.length; i++)
{
    if (Object.keys(tempArray[i]).indexOf('Name') >= 0)
    {
        // do soemthing
    }
}
```